# Jira how to show a report of user stories without tasks?

Tags: jira

Is there a way to show user stories that have no tasks?
I need this stats to be shown in a report.

Answer (score 1):

Using the JQL you can use the issueFunction not in hasSubtasks() combined with issuetype != Sub-task

So the query will look like something like the below:

```
projectname = [Name] AND (issueFunction not in hasSubtasks() AND issuetype != Sub-task)
```

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention "without using plugins".

Comment: Then I recommend using a label to mark the stories with no sub-tasks and filter based on the label.